# Which figure comes next in the series? Lines in squares

Tags: pattern, visual

I'm stuck on this one. Which one do you all think it is?

[image]

Source: http://www.vuksfrj.se/zabava/IQ%20test/testinteligencije.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like

> the (initially) left hand moves anticlockwise by 90 degrees at a time, and the (initally) right hand moves clockwise 45 degrees at a time.

So the answer is

> #4:
>  [image]